# From where can I download the UDF library which contains F_CRLF

Tags: database, firebird, user-defined-functions, firebird2.5, firebird2.1

A firebird database an application uses required F_CRLF function. When I move this database to another machine and try to access it, through a third party app I get "Invalid request BLR as offset xxx function F_CRLF is not defined. Module name or entry name cannot be found.

I tried downloading freeudflib.dll from sites and placing it in the firebird udf directory, and restarting the server, but I get the same message. I thought it could be that I have downloaded a wrong file and checking with you guys, if there is a trusted place that I could download this file from.

Comment: If copying the file doesn't work, it could also be a 32 bit / 64 bit problem. Make sure that you install the library of the right bitness.

Answer (score 1):

You can find F_CRLF function here :

http://freeadhocudf.org/index_eng.html

You can also replace this function for example :

`SELECT 'first row' || F_CRLF() || 'second row' FROM RDB$DATABASE;`

with this:

`SELECT 'first row' || ASCII_CHAR(13)||ASCII_CHAR(10)|| 'second row' FROM RDB$DATABASE;`

See :

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq132/

Comment: Sorted this by copying the UDF library that was installed on the original server. For some reason copying the freeudflib.dll did not help.